# How to calculate sum() column from dynamic list?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, dynamic

I have a dynamic list that is given below;

```
var CashReceiptDailyCollectionDetails = new List<dynamic>();
```

In the above list having TotalAmount column; How to calculate Sum of TotalAmount by using linq query from dynamic list. I was tried like below query; but it gives object referance error.

```
CashReceiptDailyCollectionDetails.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.TotalAmount))
```

Comment: Well that would happen if the list contains any null references. We can't really say anything more than that without a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps as a quick test, try `CashReceiptDailyCollectionDetails.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal( (x ?
 x.TotalAmount : 0) ))`

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal holdingNum = -1;
            var decimalsSums = CashReceiptDailyCollectionDetails.
                Select(o => o != null ?( string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.ToString()) == false?
            (decimal.TryParse(o.ToString(), out holdingNum) == true ?
            holdingNum : 0) : 0):0).Sum();
```